# How to get spring ApplicationContext in ServletContextListener?

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext, servlet-listeners

In servet class it's possible to get spring `ApplicationContext` this way

```
ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());
```

How to access `ApplicationContext` in `ServletContextListener` since `getServletContext()` method is not accessible there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `contextInitialized` :

```
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent event)
{
    ApplicationContext appCtx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(event.getServletContext());
}
```

Comment: Just to give a hint, it's org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils from spring-web